# How to check if Amazon S3 bucket is empty

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to check if an S3 bucket is empty using .NET. Particularly, I'm looking to check if a particular 'folder' is empty in the bucket, even though I know technically folders don't exist with S3.

For example:

BucketName1 > in > archived...with a sub-directory 'in' with a sub-directory 'archive' inside 'in'.

I'd like to check the 'in' folder to see if there are any files residing in it, and if not do something.

So my code looks something like

```
                // List all objects
                ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "BucketName1",
                    Prefix = job + "/in/",
                };

                ListObjectsResponse listResponse;
                // Get a list of objects
                listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
```

How do I check if just the 'in' folder contains no objects?

Comment: You have already written the code for what best can be achieved using the s3 apis for your problem in hand. What exactly are you looking for? `Assert(listResponse.S3Objects.Count == 0)`? Or you are looking for something like the subDirectories can have files but not this directory?

Answer (score 0):

- IsBucketEmpty : Request for Prefix=null and delimiter=null - Check if listResponse's S3 Object Count is zero that's means Bucket is empty
- IsFolderEmpty (Virtual Folder: S3 does not have folder) : Request for Prefix="Folder" and delimiter=null - Check if listResponse's S3 Object Count is zero  thats means Folder having prefix is empty or file(s) having prefix does not exist.